# Higher Order Function Example

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

This is a problem of CS61A in UCB. I know that a = cake() will be printed as beets in terminal.But what is the answer of a()?I have tried in Python tutor,it shows nothing after executing this code.
I'm confused why the answer like this when you input "a()" in terminal:

```
sweets
'cake'
```

In my opinion,it should be like that:

```
beets
sweets
'cake'
```

Thanks a lot.
This is my code:

```
    def cake():
        print('beets')
        def pie():
            print('sweets')
            return 'cake'
        return pie
    a = cake()
```

Comment: `a()` calls `pie` which does not log `beets`.

Comment: Is that mean "print('beets')" hasn't been executed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`a` is equal to the return value of the the called function `cake`. The returned object is a function defined in `cake`, `pie`.

When assigned `a` by calling the `cake` function.

The `cake` function is called by using this suffix `()`. When a function is called it steps through the code defined in the function.

The function first prints out the string 'beets'.

`cake` defines another function named `pie`. `pie` is not called when `cake` is called because pie is only defined and not called.

But the return value of `cake` is the function `pie`. So all you need to do is use the call suffix `()` behind the variable that `pie` was assigned to.

```
# Define the function `cake`.
def cake():
    print('beets') # Print the string, 'beets'
    def pie(): # Define a function named `pie`
        print('sweets') # `pie` prints the string 'sweets'
        return 'cake' # and returns another string, 'cake'.
    return pie # Return the pie function

# Call `cake`
a = cake() # `a` is equal to the function `pie`

# Calling `a` will call `pie`. 
# `pie` prints the string 'sweets' and returns the string 'cake'
food = a()

# the variable `food` is now equal to the string 'cake'
print(food)
```

#### Reason why 'cake' is printed when calling `a()`.

The python terminal prints 'cake' because 'cake' was returned when calling `a` and was not assigned to. So the python terminal was informing you of the return value of that function call, since you did not decide to store its value.

Comment: I agree with your point,but why "print('beets')" hasn't been executed?

Comment: `beets` is only printed when `cake()` is called, not `pie()` (a=pie)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I realized that cake() on the right hand of that assignment will just return 'cake'. so 'a' is 'pie' function which print 'sweets' with return 'None‘ and assign ’cake' to 'a'.

Comment: Right in this case the return of function `cake()` is the uncalled function `pie`. You call pie by calling the variable assigned by the return of `cake`.